# Change between mpi maps

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a parallel map where a vector is spread among different PIDs. This vector is made of a sequence of 3 numbers. Let us say that this vector is constructed as (a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, ..., an, bn, cn). I do not know how these numbers are spread on the PIDS. Now I must collect all the (a1, a2, a3, ... , an) numbers and make another map to collect them. The same for (b1, b2, b3, ..., bn) and (c1, c2, c3, ...,cn). I am new to mpi, so I have no idea on how to do this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what kind of data is located on which rank and how you expect it to be rearranged. It is unclear how your map (is it a `std::map`?) or vector is spread among the ranks.

Comment: Data are double. And the map is an EpetraMap of the package Trilinos. I do not know how my data are spread among the ranks, this is exactly my problem.

Comment: You first make a note of how long the vector is each rank, use `MPI_Allgather` to let all processes know it, then use `MPI_Allgatherv` again using the sizes that were collected in the previous step.